# calculate expiry date for a membership

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to calculate an expiry date for a membership Using c#. 
I created a form consisting of fields, and one of the fields is Join Date and Expiry Date.
Join date : when the user joining so membership starts
expiry date: when the memberships expire (which is after one year of joining)

I used JQuery Datepicker in Joining date:

```
$(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
    $("#<%=txtJoinDate.ClientID %>").datepicker();
});
```

When I selected any date, I need to auto calculate the expiry date in Expiry Date Text Box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) library for [date-time manipulations](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/).
Sample code to add 12 month:

```
$(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
    $("#<%=txtJoinDate.ClientID %>").datepicker();
    $("body").on("change","#<%=txtJoinDate.ClientID %>",function(){
        var selected = $(this).val();
        var endDateMoment = moment(selected); 
        // moment(...) can also be used to
        // parse dates in string format
        endDateMoment.add(12, 'months');

        alert(endDateMoment);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks,
I only added this code to change the txtExpiryDate to display the expiry date on the Expiry Date TextBox $("#<%=txtExpireDate.ClientID %>").val(endDateMoment);
Thanks a lot:)

Comment: I want to do a new thing regarding the expiry date: 
if we have the (altField) which will update the txtExpiryDate whenever I select a date from the datepicker, but with the same date. do you think I can increase the selected date by one year ?
I have written this code :
                $("#<%=txtJoinDate.ClientID %>").datepicker({
                    
                    altField: "#<%=txtExpireDate.ClientID%>"
                });
but I don't know what to add to increase the date by one year ... 
any idea ?

Thanks,

Comment: up vote would be appreciate. however, ask new question with fiddle to better understand your ask. thx